# Visual Studio 2017 fails to run code analysis when including atomic

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, atomic, code-analysis

I'm unable to run code analysis on files that include `<atomic>`. When this occurs, the code starts to builds (100% CPU usage) but then hangs with 0% CPU usage indefinitely. There are no warning or errors, the code just doesn't finish.

I'm currently on Visual Studio: 15.9.33.  I've had this problem for about 1.5 years now. Reinstalling the OS has not helped.

Here is a simple code snippit based on code from xatomic.h that when copy pasted into any cpp file, causes the same behavior,

```
#include <intrin0.h>

void code_analysis_hangs()
{
    auto foo = _InterlockedCompareExchange8((char *)0, 0, 0);
}

void code_analasis_success()
{
     _InterlockedCompareExchange8((char *)0, 0, 0);
}

char code_analysis_success2()
{
    return _InterlockedCompareExchange8((char *)0, 0, 0);
}
```

This same pattern appears on all `_InterlockedCompareExhange` functions as well as `_InterlockedExchange` from `intrin.h`.

:::EDIT:::
The same behavior was seen by someone else: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-code-analysis-never-finishes-under-1592/394996

I've also isolated the issue to **localespc.dll**. There are 2 plugins that get run when analysis is turned on `/analysis /analysis:plugin...EspXEngine.dll /analysis:plugin...localespc.dll`.  In my vcxproj, by manually adding the analysis options for CL.exe without the localespc.dll, code analysis seems to work and not stall while still appearing to report code analysis.

Comment: Does the problem only occur when the destination is a null pointer?

Comment: [_InterlockedCompareExchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockedcompareexchange-intrinsic-functions?view=msvc-160) does an atomic comparison of the Destination value with the Comparand value. If the Destination value is equal to the Comparand value, the Exchange value is stored in the address specified by Destination. Otherwise, does no operation. `(char *)0` is a null-pointer value of type `char *`. As far as I'm concerned, it is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @CodyGray yes nullptr also has this problem

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT are you saying that it's the `nullptr` that is causing it?  I've tried other hard coded values with the same result.

Comment: It's the `auto`.  changing the `auto` to the appropriate type allows code analysis the complete.  This doesn't solve my problem unless I start editing the visual studio header files so I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: What do you mean "nullptr also has this problem"? Both `nullptr` and `(char*)0` are *null pointers*. My question was whether this happens only when you are calling `_InterlockedCompareExchange` on null pointers. Confirming that it also happens with the `nullptr` type does not provide any more information. Does it also happen with *valid* pointers?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, yes it also happens with valid pointers.